# Draw Circuit with 'latex' with to_gate involved

Tags: qiskit, quantum-circuit

The circuit draw command doesn't work when there is a custom gate as follows:

```
qc = QuantumCircuit(2)
phi = pi/2
qc.cz(0,1)
qc.rx(5*phi,0)
qc.rx(9*phi,1)
qc.cx(0,1)
qc.rx(3*phi,0)
qc.cx(0,1)
qc.cz(0,1)
Urot = qc.to_gate()
Urot.name = "$U_\mathrm{rot}$"
ctrl_Urot = Urot.control()
ctrl_Urot.label = "C-Urot"
circ = QuantumCircuit(2)
circ.append(Urot,[0,1])
circ.draw('latex')
```

In the Jupyter notebook in VSCode, it states

```
Unable to compile LaTeX. Perhaps you are missing the `qcircuit` package. The output from the `pdflatex` command is in `latex_error.log`.
```

This is the relevant part of the error log.

```
(...\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backend-pdf
tex.def)
No file circuit.aux.
```

It works when `circ.draw('mpl')` is called, however. The package `qcircuit` is installed.

[image: Circuit with 'mpl' label]

Comment: I have just run into the identical problem!  Fortunately, as you mentioned, `mpl` gives good enough results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that the problem is related with the Qiskit's Latex math mode in the gate name `"$U_\mathrm{rot}$"`. Replacing that line for `Urot.name = "U_{\mathrm{rot}}"` shows this result in my environment:

[image: Custom Urot gate]

What you tried *should* be valid, I think, given you set `\mathrm` between curly brackets (that is `$U_{\mathrm{rot}}$`). So I reported the problem here https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/issues/9208

Answer (score 0):

If **qcircuit** and **pdflatex** are already Installed, ....

Retry after installing ***texlive***, if not downloaded in prior on your system.

Download and unzip the [zip-file](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/qcircuit/)